# What is the Maximum load a UIView in iPad can hold

Tags: ipad

I am here with an important question. Could you please help me to know how much a single uiview can be of size?. I know internal RAM of iPad is 256 MB. But my app crashes after some views are loaded. I had fixed the bugs. But still it happens. I think it is because of the Memeory leak problem. If anyone knows how much size a `UIView` can load on a single view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no fixed limit. From the docs for UIView:

> Note: Prior to iPhone OS 3.0, UIView instances may have a maximum height and width of 1024 x 1024. In iPhone OS 3.0 and later, views are no longer restricted to this maximum size but are still limited by the amount of memory they consume. Therefore, it is in your best interests to keep view sizes as small as possible. Regardless of which version of iPhone OS is running, you should consider using a CATiledLayer object if you need to create views larger than 1024 x 1024 in size.